# .bat piping multiple responses to cmd promts

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping, pipe

I am trying to pipe multiple fields to a command in my batch file (so I don't have to enter my email/pw a bunch when connecting to different environments).

I think there is a problem with the way my password is being entered / escaped. The password begins with the two single quotes, I have tried various methods of escaping these characters with no success.

Here is my .bat:

```
@echo off
SET email=my.email@email.com
SET pw=''MyPassword
SET org=some_org
SET space=some_space
SET general=https://www.someurl.com/

(
    echo %email%
    echo %pw%
    echo %org%
    echo %space%
) | cf login -a %general%
```

Here is my .bat result. Blue is where i want the data to be entered, red is sensitive info:

[image]

Here is an example of me using the command manually with the same password:
[image]

Comment: Single quotes `'` shouldn't be a problem. Do you have other unusual characters in your password (anything not letters or numbers)? When you do it manually - is the password shown in clear text or just `******`?

Comment: No the password just starts with 2 single quotes, then its just alphanumeric. The password isn't shown when typing it manually when prompted.

Comment: When it isn't shown, that *may* mean, STDIN isn't accepted (it would just accept the "Enter"). Programmers tend to not allow that for passwords. Judging by the different lengths of the blue bars batch vs. manual, that's the case here.